# Handle errors with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I try to handle 503 and 500 errors with ExpressJS but it only works with 404 error.

**My middleware :**

```
var error = function(server) {

  // 404
  server.app.use(function(request, response) {
    response.status(404);
    response.redirect('/404');
  });

  // 500
  server.app.use(function(error, request, response, next) {
    response.status(500);
    response.redirect('/500');
    next(error);
  });

  // 503
  server.app.use(function(error, request, response, next) {
    response.status(503);
    response.redirect('/503');
    next(error);
  });
};

module.exports = error;
```

**Function in my controller (using routes) :**

```
function error500(request, response) {
  response.render('0-templates/' + response.locals.options.template + '/500', {
    _layoutFile: false,
    error: //how to get the error ?
  });
}
```

Comment: Why your 500 and 503 function have not the same signature as the 404 one ?

Comment: Why use try-catch blocks and when something results in a 500 or 503 `throw new Error("internal service error")` respond with `response.status(500)` or `(503)` in your routes. Also, what happens when you swap out the first status code with 500 or 503? Is it just running 404 because it's first?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `error` argument for the `404` callback which leads *express* to believe it is a *middleware* and not an *error handler*, therefore returning 404 for every requests going through said *middleware*.

You should also add `next` argument to all *error handlers*.

From [express documentation on error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html):

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three: (err, req, res, next).

Comment: It works with `next(error)`, but I'm not able to get the error message in my controller. See edit.

Comment: _Error handlers_ are executed after _middlewares_ and _controllers_, so `next()` in an _error handler_ calls express' default _error handler_

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using 3 different functions as you have only one error handler in express, you can use something like:

```
server.app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.code) {
    res.status(err.code);
    console.log(err);
    return res.redirect('/'+err.code);
  } else {
    res.status(500);
    console.log(err);
    return res.redirect('/500');
  }
});
```

or something similar, in order to execute the error response you should call `next(err)` from your logic code

Sources: [here](https://nemethgergely.com/error-handling-express-async-await/) and [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)